# .dae file imported without armature

Tags: armature, import

I tried to import a video-game model (.dae) but it was imported without the bones. The armature modifier is there but the bones are gone.
In Maya it got imported correctly but I am only using the free trial-version so it's not a solution to use Maya...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys, I figuredit out by myself.
The armature is missing because the Default bone view is set to octraheder.
But this one only Supports wires as bones.
So to get your lovely bones you just select 'Armature' in the outliner
and then you go to armature Settings in the properties.
Now you Change the Display Settings from Octraheder to wire.